# Как верстать изображение с нестандартным режимом наложения цвета?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Всем привет! В макете имеется бэкграунд с эффектом наложения цвета soft-light. Собственно как это отобразить в верстке? Я знаю про CSS свойство background-blend-mode, но оно не поддерживается никаким IE, что меня не устраивает. "Топорный" метод растрировать стиль слоя мне тоже кажется не совсем правильным. Хочется узнать как подобную проблему решают опытные верстальщики.

Comment: На данный момент веб-страницы используются с целью предоставления контента, а не в качестве продвинутого графического интерфейса. Несмотря на все улучшения и нововведения, страницы все еще не обладают большой графической составляющей. Поэтому растрируйте, растрируйтеи еще раз растрируйте, пока лучше ничего не придумали и не ввели до конца.

Comment: ну окей, спасибо за быстрый ответ)) Просто я исходил из того, что если человек, допустим, захочет поменять изображение из админки, чтобы оверлей при этом сохранялся. Но, видимо, так не получится.

Comment: самое кроссбраузерное решение именно для ...-blend-mode скажем для режима luminosity это замена или подмена изображения , https://jsfiddle.net/8xopkv5u/1/ это самое кроссбраузерное решение , другие варианты просто не рассматривал